# Check if column exists and then do selects from table using C#

Tags: c#, sql

please can anyone point me in the right direction. I want to check if the column exists, if so do this select else do another select

```
    select case 
   when exists (
      SELECT *
      FROM Sys.columns c 
      WHERE c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.Municipality') 
         AND c.name = 'AmountTypeLabel'
   )  
   then 1
   else 0
 end
```

This Checks if column exists and then return a 0 or a 1 but there is no column name so i can't check it in C#

This is what i have tried in C# but as i said before there is no column name

```
DataTable DT;
        string SQL = "";
        try
        {

            SQL = "select case " +
                  " when exists( " +
                  "  SELECT 1 " +
                  "  FROM Sys.columns c " +
                  " WHERE c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.Municipality')" +
                  "  AND c.name = 'AmountTypeLabel'" +
                  ")" +
                  " then 1 " +
                  " else 0 " +
                  " end ";
            DT = Conn.ExecuteDT(SQL);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Unable to get Tables", ex);
        }
        return DT;
    }
```

Comment: sql query executes at database side, so why are you worry about c#? is any problem causing this statement?

Comment: No there is no error but i want to return a 0 or a 1 and call this function in another function and check if the return was a 0 or a 1 to do different selects

Comment: Try ExecuteScalar() and cast result to int

Comment: What is ExecuteDT doing?

Comment: It just gets the table with the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With existing code you can fetch the value by using the below and use it in another function:

```
if(DT.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
 //Do Something
```

***OR*** you could to use [`SQL Alias`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in your SQL query like below :

```
" end AS ColumnExists";
```

and then you can refer this in your other function. Sample snippet below -

```
 if(DT.Rows[0]["ColumnExists"].ToString() == "1")
    //Do Something
```

`On a side note` if the requirement is to fetch only the `1 or 0` from SQL server then use the [`ExecuteScalar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) as mentioned by Matteo1010 in comments.

```
 var columnExists = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
 if(columnExists.ToString() == "1")
  //Do Something
```

Comment: Glad that it helped :)